# Finding the model of an old computer i used to own?

Tags: computer-building

This might sounds ridiculous, but I need some help finding the model of an old computer i used to own. I know what the computer looks like. It was made by Packard Bell, but i can't find hardly any information on older packard bell computers anywhere online. I got the computer around 1999, give or take a couple of years. It came with Windows 98 preinstalled. It was a tower desktop. I was wondering if anyone knows of a website or reference tool where i can find some information on older model desktop computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try visiting Packard Bell's website *in the past* with the help of the [Wayback Machine](http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://packardbell.com). For example, browsing inside the [January 28, 1997](http://web.archive.org/web/19970128091233/http://www.packardbell.com/products/97models/Default.asp) snapshot, I found this:

[image: supreme]

### *drools...*

Comment: hahahaha, ah the good ol' days...

Comment: They actually had pretty interesting industrial design for that era

Comment: Back when they actually gave you some meaningful geeky specs, "pipelined burst cache" "MMX" Muh ha ha ha ....

Comment: good idea btw, don't know why i didn't think of that, but i love the wayback machine. I miss the geocities days.